# Setting up Javascript Objects for faster performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

(javascript, nodejs) I am a newb and have been hacking my way through my first large application. I am concerned about the speed of my operations and have found many solutions, but seldom explanations as to why one out does the other.

In my specific situation I have one array of objects. call it:

```
    myArray = [ { id : 1, name : steve, parentID : 34 }, { id : 2, name : Sally,
       parentID : 23}, { id : 3, name : Harry, parentID : 38} ]
```

myArray can not be changed, but I have to compile a second set of Records, which will contain this parent ID. The 2nd set can be compiled in any way. The two options I know of for compiling the data are 1. A 2nd array of Objects or 2. Making key/value pairs by pulling out the parentID as the key - to make an object of objects.

The data in the first Array of objects will never be constant, the 2nd will be fairly static with the occasional addition.

My problem is the myriad of solutions. Can anyone provide an answer that would not cause additional overhead for this already slow application and more importantly objectively explain why one solution is better than the next in terms of speed? I appreciate any insight on the topic. thank you

Comment: Should be moved to [**Code Review**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). *Code Review Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas… [...] Performance [...] then you are in the right place!**

Comment: I don't agree, he is asking for a solution to do this efficiently. Code Review is more for reviewing complete solutions or methods while this is a fairly specific problem.

Comment: This is definitely not a Code Review question - the definition of "working code" in this context is "significantly faster" so he does not have working code.

Comment: If you don't show us what you are doing (code), or for what *purpose* you're "compiling" that second set of records, we can't help you to improve its performance. Yet thanks for the very relevant information that you should be able to dynamically insert new data.

Comment: I do wonder however if the OP has actually tried to take some measurements. is the javascript runtime really your bottleneck? It just seems unlikely. Generally you want to do the simplest thing until you actually have some hard data that it's not working.

Comment: A few questions.  How many records are there generally (or a range)?  how are you looking up information in the second array?

Comment: @everyone just got back. around 200 records would be in the first array of objects and roughly 800-1000 in the one I am querying it against, but could be upwards of 2000 in rare cases

Comment: @GeorgeMauer I have not tried to take measurements, not a clue how. In this situation the user will be using a search tool to filter records from one table, which then needs to be queried against a 2nd table, but because the 2nd table is constantly being queried I am storing it in a global variable upon login.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer it is a situation where lack of speed may annoy the user

Comment: @Four_lo: Querying 2000 objects is no performance issue usually. *How* are you querying them, *what* are you searching for in the data?

Comment: @Four_lo - what I'm saying though is that I doubt that the issue is caused by "objects taking to long" at all. It is more likely caused by http request delay or database delay or disk i/o delay. Create a test program which does some similar work with objects in the same way that your project does but does nothing else, simulate a similar load. Does that part **actually** take an unacceptable amount of time?

Comment: @bergi that is good to hear, I guess I will just go at it. It is a range of dates, possibly with one other small option. Then the parent Id is taken from each of those records to query for the rest of the parent ID information. I am naive to the overhead requirements of any operation, where can I do these speed tests?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer no that is fast. I appreciate the advice. I was looking in the wrong spot for the problem. If you know of any diagnostic tools for speed tests I would appreciate it, but I should probably take this question down before people start booing me. thanks

Comment: @Four_lo I don't usually work in node so I don't know any off the top of my head but the keyword you want to look for is "profiling tools"